# Akka HTTP set response header based on result of Future

Tags: scala, rest, akka, akka-http

I'm designing a REST service using Akka-HTTP 2.0-M2 and have come across a situation where I'd like to supply additional headers which are dependent upon the reply of the queried Actor.

Currently, I have the following...

```
val route = {
  path("oncologist") {
    get {
      parameters('active.as[Boolean].?, 'skip.as[Int].?, 'limit.as[Int].?).as(GetAllOncologists) {
        req =>
          complete {
            (oncologistActor ? req).mapTo[OncologistList]
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

While this is returning without issue. I'd like to move some of the properties of OncologistList into the response header rather than returning them in the body. Namely, I'm returning total record counts and offset and I would like to generate a previous and next URL header value for use by the client. I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but have you seen http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0-M2/scala/http/common/http-model.html ? it was kind of hard to find for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use the `onComplete` and `respondWithHeaders` directives to accomplish what you want.  The `onComplete` directive works with the result of a `Future` which is exactly what `ask (?)` will return.  Here is an example using a case class like so:

```
case class Foo(id:Int, name:String)
```

And a simple route showing `onComplete` like so:

```
get{
  parameters('active.as[Boolean].?, 'skip.as[Int].?, 'limit.as[Int].?).as(GetAllOncologists) { req =>
    val fut = (oncologistActor ? req).mapTo[Foo]
    onComplete(fut){
      case util.Success(f) =>
        val headers = List(
          RawHeader("X-MyObject-Id", f.id.toString),
          RawHeader("X-MyObject-Name", f.name)
        )
        respondWithHeaders(headers){
          complete(StatusCodes.OK)
        }

      case util.Failure(ex) =>
        complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError )
    }
  }
}
```

So if we get a successful result from the `ask` on `oncologistActor` we can then leverage the `respondWithHeaders` to add some custom headers to the response.  Hopefully this is what you were looking for.